# Run bool controlled loop once more

Tags: c++, loops, boolean

```
bool loop;
do {
     ...
} while (loop);
```

I need this loop to run once more after `loop` is `false`.
I can't use integer counters to make something like `while (loop && counter > required)` as number of iterations changes with incoming data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool loop;
int n = 1;
do {
     ...
} while ((loop && n) || n--);
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty clever.

Comment: It's clever, but probably won't be obvious to anyone maintaining the code.

Answer (score 9):

```
bool loop;
do {
    loop = process(...);
} while (loop);
loop = process(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Start counting after your loop condition becomes true.

```
bool loop;
int exit_counter = 0;
do {
     // ...

     if (loop || exit_counter > 0)
         exit_counter++;
} while (exit_counter < 2);
```

I would prefer @martin.dowie's method, however. It's clearer.

Comment: And it does avoid branching.

Answer (score 1):

This would also work.

```
bool loop=true;
bool loop2=true;
do {
    if(loop==false) loop2=false;

    ......loop=false;

} while (loop || loop2);
```

i.e, use "loop OR loop2" logic expression. Initially both are true. "loop2" becomes false only one iteration after "loop" becomes false. So one extra iteration for you.